# Can't broadcast UDP Packet through LocalOnlyHotspot on Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, udp, broadcast

I've got a problem with sending and receiving UDP packet on mobile phones.
One of them is used as Receiver and second one is used as a Sender.
When I simply run my local hotspot, and then I try to broadcast a UDP packet, I get *[Error] Broadcasting messageNetwork is unreachable*

Sender class:

```
class MessageSender
    {
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SendBroadcastMessage(Context context, string text)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new UdpClient())
                {
                    client.EnableBroadcast = true;
                    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, Utils.Port);
                    var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                    return await client.SendAsync(message, message.Length, endpoint);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Error] Broadcasting message" + s.Message);
                return -999;
            }
        }
    }
```

Receiver class:

```
class MessageReceiver
    {
        private readonly UdpClient _udpClient = new UdpClient(Utils.Port);
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<UdpReceiveResult> StartListening(Context context)
        {
            _udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
            UdpReceiveResult result;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    result = await _udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    if (result.Buffer.Length > 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] in Receiving packets" + s.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```